# Memory increasing every core data iteration

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Having a memory issue while iterating through my core data objects.  As it loops through CFData (store) keeps increasing until the application crashes.  Shouldn't core data release the memory after every loop finishes?

```
for (Patient *patient in self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
    for (Exam *examForPatient in patient.exams) {
        //do stuff with examForPatient
    }
}
```

Edit - Tried the following and still behaving the same way:

```
for (Patient *patient in self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
    for (Exam *examForPatient in patient.exams) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [examForPatient.examDate description]);

        [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext refreshObject:examForPatient mergeChanges:NO];
    }
    [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext refreshObject:patient mergeChanges:NO];
}
```

Comment: @ikinciviking even an NSLog of a string in examForPatient causes it

Comment: No, every time that you access an object, it resolves the fault by loading it into memory, and it remains in memory until you tell core data to release them.

Comment: You are faulting in all your `Patient` and related `Exam` entities, they will not be released until the main runloop complete its cycle. try using an `@autoreleasepool` around the inner loop, or refresh objects you no longer need.

Comment: @DanShelly: Neither of these techniques will release the memory of a managed object.

Comment: @lnafziger refreshing and object won't release memory? and the `@autoreleasepool` is used in many of Apple's examples

Comment: Yes, refreshing will, however the first two will not for managed objects like this because the code still retains a reference to the object.  Sorry, I missed your refresh option at the end, which is what is needed. The first two will not work though.

Comment: [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4)

Comment: I realise this question is really old, but did you get to the bottom of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you no longer have need for an item to reside in memory, you can refresh it.
from the docs:
**"If you iterate over a lot of objects, you may need to use local autorelease pool blocks to ensure temporary objects are deallocated as soon as possible"**

**Edit:** see @lnafziger answer

**Note:** if you are updating your patient object or exam objects, you cannot refresh it as you will loose all changes to it (if you use `mergeChanges:YES` you will not release its memory). you will then need to save periodically and refresh the objects you no longer need.

[See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4) for more information.

Comment: The quote at the top about using autoreleasepool's is absolutely correct if you don't have any references to the objects anymore.  However an autoreleasepool won't work here because we still have valid references and they aren't "temporary objects" like your quote refers to.

Comment: However, the code that you copied letter for letter from my answer will work just fine.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you access a managed object, it fires the fault and loads the full object from the store.  It doesn't release the memory until you specifically tell it to.  Change your code to:

```
for (Patient *patient in self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
    for (Exam *examForPatient in patient.exams) {
        //do stuff with examForPatient

        // Then release the memory.  As below, save first if needed.
        [yourManagedObjectContext refreshObject:examForPatient mergeChanges:NO];
    }

    // Then release the memory - save patient first if you have made changes to it.
    [yourManagedObjectContext refreshObject:patient mergeChanges:NO];
}
```

Comment: Hmm... added in [patient.managedObjectContext refreshObject:patient mergeChanges:NO]; and it still behaves the same.  Wrong MOC?

Comment: If one patient has too many exams, you may need to do the same thing with Exams. I'll update my example.